# Why is there no warning from -Wfloat-equal when comparing containers of doubles?

Tags: c++, floating-point, clang, warnings, gcc-warning

If I use the compiler option `-Wfloat-equal` with GCC or Clang, equality comparisons of float/double values cause a warning. However, when comparing *containers* (like `std::vector` or `std::tuple`) of float or double values, no such warning is raised.

Example code (also at https://godbolt.org/z/YP8v8hTs3):

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    double d = 1.2;

    std::tuple<double, double> t_d{1.2, 3.14};
    std::tuple<double, double> t_d_2{1.2, 3.14};

    std::vector<double> v_d{1.2, 3.14};
    std::vector<double> v_d_2{1.2, 3.14};

    // this causes a warning, like "warning: comparing floating-point with '==' or '!=' is unsafe [-Wfloat-equal]":
    assert(d == 1.2);
    // but why no warning from -Wfloat-equal here?
    assert(t_d == t_d_2);
    // no warning here either:
    assert(v_d == v_d_2);

    // all of these cause warnings as expected:
    assert(std::get<0>(t_d) == 1.2);
    assert(std::get<0>(t_d) == std::get<0>(t_d_2));
    assert(v_d[0] == 1.2);
    assert(v_d[0] == v_d_2[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Why are the warnings omitted for these container comparisons? And more importantly, what can I do to actually get these warnings as well?

Comment: Practically, both the reason and the solution will be specific to the compiler and standard library (i.e. the implementation).   Most modern compilers/libraries explicitly turn off diagnostics for standard headers (mainly because users tend to complain about such things).  If that is done by the compiler, there is usually an option to turn warnings on (e.g. `-Wsystem-header` for gcc, IIRC).   If that is done in the header (e.g. by use in the headers of a pragma to suppress warnings) then you'll need to read your compiler docs on how to undo the effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**GCC** doesn't report warnings for system headers by default. The desired behavior may be obtained by adding `-Wsystem-header` compiler flag.

Quotation from the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> `-Wsystem-headers`
>
> Print warning messages for constructs found in system header files. **Warnings from system headers are normally suppressed**, on the assumption that they usually do not indicate real problems and would only make the compiler output harder to read. Using this command-line option tells GCC to emit warnings from system headers as if they occurred in user code...

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/s6rExszj6

**Clang** seemingly adopted the same approach, see https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-in-system-headers and https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-control-error-and-warning-messages.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/n9xY8rcM8